# Update Specific Cell While Others Should Remain Same

Tags: php, mysql, database

When i try to update only ISSUED textbox, i just insert a number in issued textbox, while leaving other textboxes empty. Data inserted Successfully in DB.
Only Issued textbox contains a number while all others are inserted empty.

But i want only Issued textbox to update in DB while other columns and rows should not be changed or you can say all others should be as same as they were before entering a number in issued Textbox.

Here is the query i'm currently using.. !

```
$UpdateQuery      = 
"UPDATE books SET Name='$UpdateBookName', 
Auther='$UpdateAutherName', 
Shelf='$UpdateShelf' , 
Quantity='$UpdateQuantity', 
Issued = Issued + '$UpdateIssued', 
Remaining = Quantity - Issued 
WHERE Book_Number= '$Book_Number'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not entering anything in other text boxes and still including those columns in sql update statement then it is going to set for empty value.
Query can be:

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE books SET Issued = Issued + '$UpdateIssued' WHERE Book_Number= '$Book_Number'";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is you can check your variables to see if they have anything set.

Those variables can exist as they are, if you just grab them in a previous query, so they remain updated to their existing value, so they don't get overwritten by a null value.

something like this:

```
$current = "select Name, Auther, Shelf, Quantity, Issued, Remaining
from books where WHERE Book_Number= '$Book_Number'";
```

[check rows, loop through, etc, define as `$row['variablename']` bla bla bla etc. ]

and then compare against these vs. the submit statement , so you could do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']) {
      $UpdateAutherName = $_POST['Name']; 
}
else {
    $UpdateAutherName = $row['Name'];
}
```

**Note:**  Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should look into mysqli prepared statements or PDO.  This would be more secure, and easier to work with.

Here's a sample of the select in mysqli.

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if  ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$current = $conn->prepare("select Name, Auther, Shelf, Quantity, Issued, Remaining from books where WHERE Book_Number= ?");
$current->bind_param("i",$Book_Number);
$current->execute();
$current->bind_result($Name, $Auther, $Shelf, $Quantity, $Issued, $Remaining);
$current->fetch();
$current->close();
```

This way your variables are named already  (the "i" means integer, otherwise we'd use "s" for string).  Then you can run the update, and only rename the variables if they are stored as POST.

Something like this:

```
if isset($_POST['UpdateBookName']) {

       $Name = $UpdateBookName;
}
```

and then run your update much like the original select like this:

```
$UpdateQuery = $conn->prepare("UPDATE books SET Name=?, 
Auther=?, 
Shelf=? , 
Quantity=?, 
Issued = Issued + ?, 
Remaining = Quantity - Issued 
WHERE Book_Number= ?");
$UpdateQuery->bind_param("sssiii", $Name, $Auther, $Shelf, $Quantity, $Issued, $Book_Number);
$UpdateQuery->execute();
$UpdateQuery->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this just an idea
you have input like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inpuform" name="inputform" action="" method="post">
 book number<input type="text" name="bookno" value="N09A"><br>
 book name<input type="text" name="bookname"><br>
 auther<input type="text" name="auther"><br>
 shelf<input type="text" name="shelf"><br>
 qty<input type="text" name="qty"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="outputmessage"></div>
<script>
var bookno = $('#bookno').text();
$('#inpuform').on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
        url: 'proccess.php',
        data: $('#inpuform').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function( data ){
         console.log(data);
   $('#outputmessage').html(data);
  }
 });
}); 
</script>
```

post serialize variable to **proccess.php** with ajax
then handle in php

```html
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$arrbookno = array_slice($data, 0, 1);
$bookno = $arrbookno['bookno'];
$restdata = array_slice($data, 1);
$arrkey = array();
$arrvalue = array();
$holdvar = "";
foreach ($restdata as $key => $value) {
 if (!empty($value)) {
  array_push($arrkey, $key);
  array_push($arrvalue, $value);
  $holdvar .= $key."='".$value."', ";
 }
}
$cleanvar = rtrim($holdvar, ", ");
$update = "UPDATE books SET ".$cleanvar." WHERE Book_Number=".$bookno;
echo $update;
?>
```

but this example should run whenever you put book no as first input element
hope this help...